# WP admin display custom field if another field value is "Female"

Tags: metabox, wp-admin

I have 3 custom fields: Gender, Partner name, and Partner last name.

I need a js or CSS function. If I select "Female" from `ecpt_gender` select box, 2 custom fields appear by CSS changing the display property from `display:none` to `display:block`.

Comment: Do you want to make this happen on backend? If so how have you achieved dropdown for Gender under custom fields? Please provide more details so that I may assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your question is off-topic here, because it's javascripts specific and not specific to WordPress. But I'm answering it and making it more WordPress-centric so that others get help too.

The following function will enqueue a `custom.js` file from your theme folder's `/js` subfolder to only admin panel (put it in `functions.php` of your theme):

```
function my_admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts' );
```

Now in the `custom.js` file write down the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var field_one = $('#field_one');
    var field_two = $('#field_two');

    //hiding the field first
    field_one.hide();
    field_two.hide();

    //on value change
    $('[name="ecpt_gender"]').on('change', function(){
       //we're checking what the value we've got
       if( $(this).val() === 'Female' ) {
          field_one.show(); //you can use slideDown() instead of show() for some animation
          field_two.show();
       } else {
          field_one.hide();
          field_two.hide();
       }
    });
});
```

If you want to load the scripts only to a certain page, use `$current_screen` Global inside the function:

```
function my_admin_scripts() {
    global $current_screen;
    //var_dump( $current_screen ); //check what you've got using this variable
    if( 'post.php' === $current_screen || 'post-new.php' === $current_screen )
         wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts' );
```

Always take precaution about JS-based show/hide fields, because they are good when inserting data, but they may not functional when updating/editing data. So take precaution there like the following:

Inside your metabox fields use `get_post_meta()` and show the fields accordingly:

```
$ecpt_gender_db_val = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'field_name', true ); //fetching single value

if( $ecpt_gender_db_val && $ecpt_gender_db_val === 'Female' ) {
    //show the fields associated with 'Female' value
}
```

But in my opinion it's safer doing JS more specific, if that's specific only to the New Post page:

```
var field_one = $('body.post-new-php #field_one');
```

Doing so will make the item selection more specific to only the add new page, and it won't be applicable to the edit page. I'm using the dynamic `<body>` class to target page-specific items.

Comment: Thank you, how can i add On page load, if ecpt_gender is Female,    field_one.show(); field_two.show();

Comment: It's the [`document.ready()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+on+page+load) function we've shown here.